# JSF URL Routing

Tags: jsf, url, url-rewriting

Hi is there option in JSF to generate link like that:

```
localhost:8080/something/:myParamHere
```

Closest thing I've achieved with this was URL like:

```
localhost:8080/something?id=55
```

but I need:

```
localhost:8080/something/55
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite request parameters to nearly any URL with Pretty Faces (http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

Example:

```
@URLMapping(id = "process", pattern = "/process/#{processId}", viewId = "/faces/page/process.xhtml")
```